# Reloading single row in PFTableViewCell - Returns that PFTableViewCell does not have cellForRowMethod

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview, uitableview, cell-formatting

Ok so I've been trying to make a like button for an app I'm working on and I'm using parse as a backend. So far I can update the like button in parse, however, I can only reload the entire tableview not just the single cell. Reloading the entire tableview sometimes causes the tableview to move up or down I believe because of different sized cells.

```
      @IBAction func topButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: hitIndex!) as TableViewCell
    //var indexOfCell:NSIndexPath

    //indexOfCell = hitIndex!
    if object.valueForKey("likedBy") != nil {

        var UUIDarray = object.valueForKey("likedBy")? as NSArray
        var uuidArray:[String] = UUIDarray as [String]

        if !isStringPresentInArray(uuidArray, str: uuid) {

            object.addObject(uuid, forKey: "likedBy")
            object.incrementKey("count")
            object.saveInBackground()                
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried the cellForRow with the proper indexPath and it always returns that PFTableViewCell does not contain the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I read on a forum that someone was able to create a custom method to reload the cell and Parse's documentation uses PAPCache to do the like button. Lucky for me the documentation for the like button on Parse's page is in Obj-C and I've coded my app in Swift. Here's the link to the page if you want to see: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anypic#like. Section 6.1.

**TD;LR** I'm unsure how to update the cell so the entire tableview does not get reloaded without the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Maybe Custom method? Maybe PAPCache method?

**SOLVED**

```
  if object.valueForKey("likedBy") != nil {
        var UUIDarray = object.valueForKey("likedBy")? as NSArray
        var uuidArray:[String] = UUIDarray as [String]
        if !isStringPresentInArray(uuidArray, str: uuid) {
            object.addObject(uuid, forKey: "likedBy")
            object.incrementKey("count")
            object.saveInBackground()
            let count = object.valueForKey("count") as Int?
            //cell.count.text = "\(count)"
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

This properly reloads only the cell, however, now my entire tableview always scrolls to the top which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to with the UUID; hitpoint ;hitIndex, and I don't understand what you want your app to do and I don't have and experience with parse ? I would comment on your question,but I need 50 rep to do this.Sorry that this isn't an answer,but a question .And if you are referring about cellForRowAtIndexPath,you need a UITableView not a cell.

Comment: Actually I solved this problem using cellForRow I just had to properly put the indexPath into an array and make it an optional so it succeeded. Now though the whole tableview keeps scrolling up when press the like button. ;(